# Getting TortoiseSVN/TortoiseGit icon overlays in 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, 64-bit, tortoisegit

When installing TortoiseHg on Windows x64, I have an option to install both x86 and x64 shell extensions, which is useful, as [my favorite Windows Explorer replacement](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.htm) is 32-bit. But there is no such options for TortoiseGit or TortoiseSVN, so working with them requires opening Explorer windows.

I know it's possible to install 32 and 64-bit versions of TortoiseSVN side by side, but:

1. Is there a way to share settings between them?
2. Does the same apply to TortoiseGit?

Comment: I could not install 32-bit version of recent TortoiseSVN (1.7.1.22161) under 64-bit windows: it fails pre-setup check and refuses to install. What to do?

Comment: Just run into the same problem. I had to revert to Total Commander 32bit, since our company deployed Digital Guardian and it break Total Commander 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some problems with TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN. Context menu and overlay icons weren't shown in Total Commander 32bit on Windows 7 64bit. I solved my problem this way:

**TortoiseGit**

1. Install [mSysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) using network installer into C:\msysgit. It will unpack and compile Git for Windows.
2. Install [Git preview](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) into C:\Program Files (x86)\Git.
3. Install [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) 64bit version into C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit. Choose OpenSSH or Putty (if you use GitHub). The newest version should support 32bit context menu (if not, you must install also 32bit version of TortoiseGit).
4. Set the Git.exe path in TortoiseGit settings: C:\msysgit\bin. Set user info in Git/Config section.

**TortoiseSVN**

1. Install [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) 64bit version into C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN.
2. Install [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) 32bit version into C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN.

Comment: As for recent 32-bit TortoiseSVN (1.7.1.22161) - it refuses to install under win64.

Comment: With recent versions of TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit the x86 explorer extension is also included in the x64 installer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same context (Windows 7, 64 bit, using TotalCommander as a 32 bit application), and it works like that for me:

- I have installed both the 32bit and 64bit versions of TortoiseSVN.
- In the Windows Explorer, I have (only) visible the 64bit application, everything works fine.
- In the TotalCommander, I have the 32bit application integrated directly in the context menu, and additionally the (not used) 64bit application through a sub-menu `x64 > TortoiseSVN`.
- When I change some configuration in the 32bit or 64bit TortoiseSVN, it is the same configuration. So the configurations are shared between the two. For me, it is located under `c:\Users\mliebelt\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\`.

[image: Submenu in TotalCommander for 64bit applications]

So it works (mostly) for me. The  drawbacks are:

- 2 installations, that should go together. Same major and minor versions, so no conflict will arise from different implementations (e.g. change in working copy layout). Is the same with the SVN command you use in the shell.
- Two processes running to compute the current status of the working copy, to show it as overlay in the TotalCommander and Windows Explorer. [image]

PS: I use only TortoiseGit in the 64bit version, but use mostly the shell command `git`.

Comment: With recent versions of TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit the x86 explorer extension is also included in the x64 installer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [64-bit Total Commander 8 beta](http://www.ghisler.com/whatsnew.htm) version which solved this problem for me.